# Is it Possible to Generate Custom Client Stubs from a WSDL generated from code?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

A web service is developed using Code First Approach by a different team. WSDL is generated at runtime.
We want to generate client stubs from this WSDL but instead of using the targetNameSpace value as our package, we want to customize package Name.
Is it Possible?

Comment: It depends on the framework you are using for your stub generation.

Comment: Are you saying you want to generate the client stubs at runtime?  Or would it be sufficient to capture the WSDL at runtime and then call `wsimport` on it before compiling?

Comment: @slowy  I am using Jaxws-maven-plugin? Which frameworks can it be done and in which it can't? Can you please list a few?

Comment: @VGR I do not want client stubs runtime. WSDL is already existing created by the code of web service. I just want to generate Client stubs but customize package Name. I am unable to do so with Jaxws-maven-plugin. And A person in my team says its not possible because this is code first approach. I want to know if its possible or not.

Comment: Your teammate is incorrect.  Whether the other team used a code-first approach has nothing to do with it.  You have a WSDL;  it doesn't matter how the WSDL was generated.  The standard `wsimport` tool comes with every JDK, and it has an option that allows you to specify the name of the package which the generated classes will belong to.  I'm not sure how to do that in Maven, though it looks like [putting a `<packageName>` element in the configuration section](https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/usage.html) may be enough.

Comment: @DolphinJava I googled "jaxws-maven-plugin package name" and found a possible answer, did you?

Comment: Appreciate your interest and responses. Let me add some more context. We are trying to generate Client Stubs using packageName tag in POM for plugin jaxws-maven-plugin. However, it keeps giving an error and does not generates code. However, if I remove the packageName tag, the same configuration works. I spent a lot of time researching possible work arounds and resolutions however, was unable to resolve. In today's discussion, my colleague gave this statement. I decided to ask this.

Comment: I tried the same approach of using PackageName tag in POM for plugin jaxws-maven-plugin for a different WSDL. This is a WSDL for a webservice that I deployed on my local machine. And this approach for customizing packageName worked with no problem. So far, only deduction is there something unique to that WSDL which is making it fail. As of now we do not understand it.